# C# Func with Lambda Expressions

Tags: c#, func

I am struggling to get my head around some c# codes. I am trying to find the documentation that provides the Syntax description for such usage of Func Delegates.

```
public class Person 
{
 public string name {get; set;}
 public int Age {get; set:}
}
           
Func<Person, bool> IsOlderOrEqual(int age) =>
                pm => pm.Age >= age;
```

From interpreting the syntax documentation, my understanding was, the parameter had to be type T which is Person in this case.

```
public delegate TResult Func<in T, out TResult>(T arg);
```

I have also come across codes like

```
 Func<SomeClass, bool> isActiveSelector = it => it.IsActive;
```

I am wondering if there is  documentation from Microsoft about different syntax variations used for Func delegate, specially in conjunction with lambda operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Func<Person, bool> IsOlderOrEqual(int age) => pm => pm.Age >= age;` is a [*method*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods) that returns `Func<Person, bool>` and is [expression-bodied](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members). It can be rewritten as

```cs
Func<Person, bool> IsOlderOrEqual(int age)
{
    return pm => pm.Age >= age;
}
```

`Func<SomeClass, bool> isActiveSelector = it => it.IsActive;` is a *variable* of type `Func<SomeClass, bool>` that is initialized with the value `it => it.IsActive`.

Comment: I would advise calling it a "method" rather than a "function". There are other things now that are actually called functions, like *local functions*, while this falls under what's generally called a method, even if it's expression-bodied.

Comment: @madreflection You can have both the expression-bodied and the non-expression-bodied versions as either a "method" or a "local function".

Comment: Right... I wasn't saying it was wrong, and that's why I didn't edit the answer. But, "method" is the official term for what the `IsOlderOrEqual` program element is.

Comment: @madreflection [It is indeed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods), which is a shame in my opinion (unless, amusingly, it is a local function which it also may be).